# Looping Over Async Calls by Emulating .reduce() with async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, functional-programming, emulation, reduce

**Variables & Functions used in the code:**

```
const fakeAPI = (delay, value) =>
 new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), delay));

const useResult = x => console.log(new Date(), x);
```

**This code prints what forEach cant with async calls by using a reduce() implementation instead:**

```
const forEachAsync = (arr, fn) =>
 arr.reduce(
 (promise, value) => promise.then(() => fn(value)),
 Promise.resolve()
 );
(async () => {
 console.log("START FOREACH VIA REDUCE");
 await forEachAsync([1, 2, 3, 4], async n => {
 const x = await fakeAPI(n * 1000, n);
 useResult(x);
 });
 console.log("END FOREACH VIA REDUCE");
})();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/*
START FOREACH VIA REDUCE
2019-10-13T20:02:23.437Z 1
2019-10-13T20:02:24.446Z 2
2019-10-13T20:02:25.949Z 3
2019-10-13T20:02:27.952Z 4
END FOREACH VIA REDUCE
*/
```

What is the purpose of promise and value parameter in the `arr.reduce` function in the context of main code block?

Is **value** parameter passed to the **async n** arrow function?

Even though, I would prefer the explanation because I am studying functional-prog, but, if there is any other way of handling this in a FP manner, I would be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev thanks a lot. thou do you have any comments on the questions? I would love to hear them.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're asking. Are you looking for an explanation of how to enumerate async objects or how does reduce work?

Comment: basically, what i ask is how does the custom forEachAsync function work in the second code block?

Comment: @afyonkes Do you know how `reduce` works with synchronous functions? And how it expands to a call chain?

Comment: yes i know how reduce works. this one is actually from a book about functional programming i was studying. i couldnt get the code it seemed so complicated. so wanted to ask for a senior. its my first month in coding without degree so i try to get down below to the fundamentals. this is not how you proceed in a project probably but like i told, i want to know the possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**forEach**

`forEach` is a side effect the code you are studying is bad. The example uses `async` and `await` so using `.reduce` to chain `.then` calls makes no sense. That said, we can implement it if you want to experience the pain of its usage -

```js
async function forEach (arr, fn)
{ for (const x of arr)
    await fn(x)         // <- return value of fn disappears
}

const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const fakeApi = x =>
  sleep(1000).then(_ => `api response: ${x * x}`)

forEach
  ( [1,2,3,4]
  , async x =>
      // side effect tangled with task processing code
      console.log((new Date).toUTCString(), await fakeApi(x))
  )
  .then(console.log, console.error) // <- no values beyond this point
```

```js
"Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:46:35 GMT" "api response: 1"   // <- :35
"Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:46:36 GMT" "api response: 4"   // <- :36
"Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:46:37 GMT" "api response: 9"   // <- :37
"Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:46:38 GMT" "api response: 16"  // <- :38
undefined
```

To remedy the issues above, notice how `serial` and `parallel` (below) keep the data contained *within* the promise instead of pushing values out using side effects like `console.log` or `useResult`.

**serial**

We can write `serial` which processes task in *serial* order -

```js
async function serial (arr, fn)
{ let r = []
  for (const x of arr)
    r.push(await fn(x))
  return r
}

const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const fakeApi = x =>
  sleep(1000).then(_ => `api response: ${x * x}`)

serial
  ( [1,2,3,4]
  , async x => [ (new Date).toUTCString(), await fakeApi(x) ]
  )
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```js
[
  [
    "Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:39:04 GMT",  // <- :04
    "api response: 1"
  ],
  [
    "Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:39:05 GMT",  // <- :05
    "api response: 4"
  ],
  [
    "Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:39:06 GMT",  // <- :06
    "api response: 9"
  ],
  [
    "Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:39:07 GMT",  // <- :07
    "api response: 16"
  ]
]
```

**parallel**

Or we can write `parallel` which processes the tasks in *parallel* -

```js
const parallel = (arr, fn) =>
  Promise.all(arr.map(v => fn(v)))

const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const fakeApi = x =>
  sleep(1000).then(_ => `api response: ${x * x}`)

parallel
  ( [1,2,3,4]
  , async x => [ (new Date).toUTCString(), await fakeApi(x) ]
  )
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```js
[
  [
    "Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:40:47 GMT",  // <- :47
    "api response: 1"
  ],
  [
    "Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:40:47 GMT",  // <- :47
    "api response: 4"
  ],
  [
    "Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:40:47 GMT",  // <- :47
    "api response: 9"
  ],
  [
    "Sat, 30 Jan 2021 16:40:47 GMT",  // <- :47
    "api response: 16"
  ]
]
```

Comment: this is a neater version of the code i guess. my example was too complicated for a beginner like me. it is so much easier to understand your code. the idea of implementing reduce -as the author states- is because forEach mutates the object in async functions if i remember correctly. Trying to be pure from the start. Dont want my code to be all over the place. thanks for your time.

Comment: @afyonkes glad i could peel the complexity away for you. `forEach` itself does not mutate anything, but it is common to use mutation (and other side effects) in the forEach callback. in fact `forEach` has no other purpose other than to trigger side effects. async functions also have no opinion on whether you mutate objects within them. it's completely up to how you use them. if you have any other questions i'm happy to help.